# How to make C# chart with two columns per one X value?

Tags: c#, charts

I need chart:

```
|          _
|  _      | | _
| | | _   | || |
| | || |  | || |
|----|-------|------
     1       2
```

I've tried to do this by code below, but second column overlaps first.But must be second column is next to first column

```
        chart.Series.Clear();
        chart.Series.Add("series 1");
        chart.Series.Add("series 2");

        for (int i = 0; i < alphabet.Length; i++)
        {
            DataPoint dp = new DataPoint();
            dp.AxisLabel = alphabet[i].ToString();
            dp.YValues = new double[] { freq[i] };

            chart.Series[0].Points.Add(dp);

            dp.YValues = new double[] { 100 };
            chart.Series[1].Points.Add(dp);
        }
```

Comment: Can you please be more descriptive?  What are you trying to do, what isn't working, HOW is it not working?  Is the problem that the physical layout of the columns overlap, or is it that the data overlaps?

Comment: We can't even tell which Chart class.

Comment: Which charting library are you using? Looks like [System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datavisualization.charting.aspx), is that right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The columns are not aligning because you are using the same instance of DataPoint. Use a new instance of DataPoint for your second series and they will be rendered besides each other.

```
chart.Series.Clear();
    chart.Series.Add("series 1");
    chart.Series.Add("series 2");

    for (int i = 0; i < alphabet.Length; i++)
    {
        DataPoint dp = new DataPoint();
        dp.AxisLabel = alphabet[i].ToString();
        dp.YValues = new double[] { freq[i] };

        chart.Series[0].Points.Add(dp);



        DataPoint dp1 = new DataPoint();
        dp1.AxisLabel = alphabet[i].ToString();
        dp1.YValues = new double[] { 100 };
        chart.Series[1].Points.Add(dp1);
    }
```